# How to insert image as background using CSS?

Tags: html, css

I want to insert image as background without using the `<img/>` tag.
I've tried the following code:

HTML:

```
<body>

     <div class="icon"> </div>

</body>
```

CSS:

```
.icon 
{
    background-image:url("Pictures/control.png");
}
```

I've also tried #icon in the CSS, but it won't display anything again. If I use the img tag `<img src="Pictures/control.png" />` it works.

Could you show me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: are you sure about the path `"Pictures/control.png"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `.icon` has no contents you'll need to set a size.

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/gCWU3

```
.icon {
    background-image:url(...);
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
}
```

Comment: It works, it was the size, thanks a lot !
I didn't know that i must specify a size mandatory

Comment: Just an other little quesiton, for a size with % it doesn't work, why ?

Comment: It does, but you have to have a parent with a height: http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/gCWU3/2/

Answer (score 0):

Path is correct.

```
<div class="icon"></div>
```

example:

```
.icon {
 display: block;
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
 background:url("Pictures/control.png") 0 0 no-repeat;
}
```

opt a http://jsfiddle.net/B2Y6N/

opt b http://jsfiddle.net/B2Y6N/1/

Comment: @user3250142 modified

Comment: The image path is relative to the CSS file. So, if you don't have the `Pictures` folder in the same as the CSS file, the path is not correct. It is probably something liki `../Pictures/control.png`.